# Possible to re-order Python API ENUM's?

Tags: python

I will try to explane.
Lets say,

class BLA_bla_tratata(Menu):

```
bl_label = "Ololo"

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(context.space_data, "viewport_shade", expand=True)
```

This define viewport shade menu... As I understand "viewport_shade" is a  PROPERTY and it is a LIST of some values ( "MATERIAL", "TEXTURED", "SOLID"....)

So what is exactly I need to know - is there any way to reorder this list befor saying

row.prop(context.space_data, "viewport_shade", expand=True)

For example ( "MATERIAL", "TEXTURED", "SOLID"....) -> ("SOLID", "TEXTURED", "MATERIAL", ....)
Or - how can I get access to this data  in blender
Thx!

Comment: Can you say why you want this ability?

Comment: Yes. Scripting pie menus, it will be cool to just reorder this property list to change places of different pie-menu-elements. So it is just idea. I have done this other way.

For example I replace this line : `pie.prop(context.space_data, "viewport_shade", expand=True)`

to that :
        pie.prop_enum(context.space_data, "viewport_shade", "MATERIAL")
        pie.prop_enum(context.space_data, "viewport_shade", "RENDERED")
        pie.prop_enum(context.space_data, "viewport_shade", "WIREFRAME").........

Comment: In that case you could better ask a question about how to re-arrange pi-menus.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't re-order them. If the enums are defined in Python its possible to unregister the property and re-register a new enum, based on the old one but with a different ordering, however that seems like an awful lot of effort.

Basically, its not supported.